# Find $\iiint_V z$ with $V=\lbrace(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3} : y\geq0, z\geq0, x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 2, x^2+y^2\leq1\rbrace$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, cylindrical-coordinates

Let $f(x,y,z)=z$ and $T=\lbrace(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3} : y\geq0, z\geq0, x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 2, x^2+y^2\leq1\rbrace$

Find $\iiint_T f(x,y,z) dV$

I'm having a few problems with this integral, here's what I've done:

I found that $0\leq z \leq \sqrt{2-x^2-y^2}$.

And then I'm having problems with the $x$-$y$ bounds:

I get two equations: $x^2+y^2\leq2$ and $x^2+y^2\leq1$, and as $y\geq0$ I get this:

[image]

I then, convert to polar coordinates, and I get $r\leq \sqrt2$ and $r\leq1$, but with the given $T$, I thought ? that I had to integrate from $r=0$ to $r=\sqrt2$:

$\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt2}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2-x^2-y^2}} z$ $dz r dr d\theta = \int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt2}\frac{z^2}{2}\Big|_0^\sqrt{2-x^2-y^2}$ $rdrd\theta=\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt2}\frac{2-x^2-y^2}{2}$ $rdrd\theta$

At this point I convert $\frac{2-x^2-y^2}{2}$ to polar coordinates:

$\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt2}\frac{2-r^2}{2}$ $rdrd\theta = \int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt2}\frac{2r-r^3}{2}$ $drd\theta = \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{r^2}{2}-\frac{r^4}{4}\Big|_0^\sqrt{2}d\theta=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{2} d\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ which is the wrong answer...

The correct answer would be:

> \begin{align} \iiint_T f(x,y,z) dV = \frac{3\pi}{8} \end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^{2}+y^{2} \leq 1$ **automatically implies** $x^{2}+y^{2} \leq 2$ so igonre this second condition. $\theta$ varies from $0$ to $\pi$ and $r$ from $0$ to $1$. Now see if you get the correct answer.

Comment: Oooo didn't think about that! thank you so much!!! I got the right answer now :-)